# Passing data from route handler to jade template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm putting together a basic project admin/management site and decided to finally learn to use node/express/monk/jade/redis, the works. Everything was going fine but I've run into a problem trying to get data passed between the route handler in index.js and the jade template file.

in `index.js`

```
exports.auth = function( db )
{

    return function( req, res )
    {

        var userName      = req.body.username,
            userPassword  = req.body.password,
            authenticated = false;

        // check credentials code
        // ...

        if (authenticated)
        {
            // set some session stuff
            res.redirect( "home" );  // good to go
        }
        else
        {
            res.locals.err = "Authentication error";
            res.redirect( "login" );  // show err on login page
        }

    }
}
```

in `login.jade`

```
- if (typeof( locals.err ) !== 'undefined' ) {
    p.errormsg #{ locals.err }
- }
```

Iterating over `locals` in the jade template it doesn't show an entry for `err`. Does `res.redirect()` wipe out the err entry I made in `index.js`? Or am I actually dealing with two different objects (`res.locals` in `index.js` and `locals` in the jade template)?

My original approach was to use `res.render( "login", { "err" : "Authentication err" } )` instead of redirecting, but I cannot figure out how to get the browser to show `/login` and not `/auth` when the error happens. I tried

```
res.location( "login" );
res.render( "login", { "err" : "Authentication err" });
```

but the browser still shows `/auth`.

The only other approach I found was using session data. The session object is available in both places and I can set/read the information from it as needed. The solution is inelegant though since the session info persists through reloads of the login page so the browser just keeps showing the error message for the original attempt rather than reloading/rendering a clean login page.

Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: I should note that the last 4+ hours of searching/reading has led me to believe that some sort of middleware is what I need. However I can't for the life of me figure out what to add to my app.js to get index.js and the jade template to write/read the locals object correctly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - the redirect is returning a redirect to the client, which makes a separate request from the client. Your prior `res.locals.err` is long gone. You may want to read the [doc on `res.redirect()`](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#res.redirect).

Session data would be a sensible way to handle this unless you are a hardcore about statelessness. I am not sure why you find it inelegant. Why don't you reset that element of the session data after you render the next page?

There are different ways you can handle your issue about what the location bar shows if you search around for some javascript. Feels like a bit of kludge though.

Personally, I just have a `/login` path - called via `GET` it displays the login page, called via `POST` it authenticates, redirects if successful, or renders the login template with the error if the login is bad. No session data necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm only watching state as a matter of course for this learning project. I'd like to reserve session data for things that must persist between requests. For now I'm going to follow your very sensible suggestion of using the same `/login` route to handle both the `GET` and `POST`. That approach gets me what I'm looking for here, I just wish I'd figured out the locals usage as that's still kinda muddy for me. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. FWIW, I think your local usage is just fine, it's just that in this scenario, you ended up with two local scopes, one per request. Regarding the dual GET/POST approach - getting the setup right can be trickier than it feels like it should (or I glossed over something in the doc). I have found it most reliable if I bind the same function to both request types and then have that single function do a request type check rather than two separate functions bound each to one request type. Good luck with it!